# Copying Files Silently with xcopy - Python Windows 10

Tags: python, user-interface, cmd, cx-freeze, xcopy

I have a quick question involving Copying files.When copying files in a script I am using the following:

`os.system('echo f | xcopy /f /y "{source}" "{target}"'.format(source=source, target=target))`

I use this because it is MUCH faster than `shutil.copyfile(source, target)`. This works fine, but it prints out this ugly prompt string in the console for each file copied (see image below).

[image]

And if I compile the program to an exe file (using `cx_Freeze`) without the CMD window being open for a GUI, it rapidly opens and closes a CMD window when each file is copying (like a flicker). So if I am copying 30 files, a CMD window flickers open and closed 30 times.

Is there any way to silence this? Maybe through a flag or something? Or possibly some other method entirely that I could use that is as equally as efficient as `xcopy` without the annoying prompt and flickering windows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
os.system('echo f | xcopy /y "{source}" "{target}" > nul'.format(source=filename, target=filename_txt))
```

Works fine in my machine.